# Why does this unity gain transistor phase shifter not drop its amplitude with frequency?

Tags: analog, circuit-analysis, active-filter

I read about this phase shifter in "the Art of Electronics" and decided to run an LTspice simulation to verify if my understanding of the circuit is in line with reality.

[image]

According to LTspice the circuit is just below unity gain over 10Hz-100kHz band.

[image]

The dashed line shows phase. The continuous line shows amplitude, but notice the scale: Looking at µV's variation from a 1V(p) input.

My feeling however tells me R5 and C2 form a simple RC low pass filter and although fed by a symmetric input voltage tapped from the transistor's collector and emitter, I would still expect the output to drop at 6dB/oct from about 200Hz.

**AC analysis:**

- As C2 current increases with frequency, the voltage across R5 increases.
- Similarly the voltage across C2 decreases.
- Amplitude fed into the R5/C2 at collector and emitter is flat with frequency.

What am I overlooking here, why is the output gain for higher frequencies still about unity? I am looking for a qualitative answer.

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 892 680
WIRE 288 16 112 16
WIRE 832 16 288 16
WIRE 112 48 112 16
WIRE 288 48 288 16
WIRE 832 48 832 16
WIRE 288 144 288 128
WIRE 400 144 288 144
WIRE 512 144 480 144
WIRE 288 160 288 144
WIRE -16 208 -208 208
WIRE 112 208 112 128
WIRE 112 208 48 208
WIRE 224 208 112 208
WIRE 512 208 512 144
WIRE 528 208 512 208
WIRE 608 208 608 80
WIRE 608 208 592 208
WIRE 640 208 608 208
WIRE 752 208 720 208
WIRE 832 208 832 128
WIRE 832 208 752 208
WIRE -208 240 -208 208
WIRE 752 240 752 208
WIRE 288 272 288 256
WIRE 400 272 288 272
WIRE 512 272 512 208
WIRE 512 272 464 272
WIRE 112 288 112 208
WIRE 288 288 288 272
WIRE 832 288 832 208
WIRE -208 352 -208 320
WIRE 112 400 112 368
WIRE 288 400 288 368
WIRE 288 400 112 400
WIRE 832 400 832 368
WIRE 832 400 288 400
FLAG 752 240 0
FLAG -208 352 0
FLAG 608 80 out
SYMBOL res 96 32 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 62k
SYMBOL res 96 272 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 22k
SYMBOL res 272 32 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 2k203742
SYMBOL res 272 272 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 2k2
SYMBOL res 384 160 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 8k
SYMBOL cap -16 224 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 10m
SYMBOL npn 224 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value 2N3904
SYMBOL voltage 832 272 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL voltage 832 32 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL voltage -208 224 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 1 20000)
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1 0
SYMBOL cap 528 224 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 10�
SYMBOL res 624 224 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 10meg
SYMBOL cap 400 288 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 0.1�
TEXT -242 410 Left 2 !.tran 0 0.2 0.1
TEXT -248 448 Left 2 !;ac dec 50 10 100000
```

Comment: You should post the plot, but in lieu of that, since you've already generated it,  how about posting the circuit list so we don't have to  generate it from your schematic?

Comment: @EMFields I didn't include the plot because ... well it is flat. Hang on, I'll upload it.

Comment: Does the voltage divider involving R6=10M have an effect?

Comment: @Chu No I chose the values high enough to have very little effect. Notice that the output of the phase shifter is in the order of 10k, and the C3/R6-load order magnitude 10M. A factor 1000+ difference.

Comment: OK, thanks... I'll get into it later. Right now it's about  0545 and my body is begging me to to put it to bed for a while.

Comment: Is voltage divider at the output: \$\frac{R_6((1+sC_2R_5)}{R_6(1+sC_2R_5)+R5}\$, which is approximately unity since R6=10M?

Comment: Because the value of R3 has been fiddled to compensate for the base current at one very specific value of hFE. To maintain this accuracy at LF you'll need to adjust R3 for the actual transistor on every one you build. (Or set R3 to 2k2, resimulate, and decide if that's an acceptable worst case error).

Comment: @BrianDrummond I fiddled with R3 experimenting to flatten response with the used transistor because of being curious how well the result could be and indeed I am aware of the fact that I can't buy the exact components used. Indeed compensating for the base current in the emitter branch. I probably should've reset it to 2k2 before posting. In the plot at the scale used in my post, the difference is barely noticable. The experiment with R3 was just to figure out how much difference Ic/Ie asymmetry would have, but is otherwise unrelated to the question itself.

Comment: I'm studing a circuit very similar to this one, used on SQ record's decoder. Did you take this circuit from "the Art of Electronics" by Horowvitz & Hill?

Answer (score 5):

> My feeling however tells me R5 and C2 form a simple RC low pass filter
>   and although fed by a symmetric input voltage tapped from the
>   transistor's collector and emitter, I would still expect the output to
>   drop at 6dB/oct from about 200Hz

At low frequencies R5 is dominant and the output is 180 deg phase shifted and unity gain (near enough) and at high frequencies C2 is dominant and produces a zero phase shift because the voltage feeding C2 is from the emitter.

There is no significant low pass filtering to consider here.

Consider that the voltage at the emitter is the same as the voltage at the base and call it Vin. The voltage at the collector is -Vin: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftS6sv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Therefore the voltage at the midpoint of R and C (Vout) is: -

\$V_{IN} - \dfrac{2V_{IN} \cdot X_C}{X_C+R} = V_{IN}(1-\dfrac{2X_C}{R+X_C})\$

Therefore Vout/Vin = \$\dfrac{R-X_C}{R+X_C}\$

This is all without using complex numbers but if you did the analysis of top and bottom of the equation above, the magnitudes are equal: -

[image]

The above picture is when R and Xc are vectorially added together. Now if Xc was negative (as per the numerator in the equation), Xc would, of course point upwards BUT, the length of -Xc and R added together is exactly the same magnitude.

Comment: I indeed overlooked the fact that I can neglect C2 for low frequencies and R5 for high frequencies, thnx. That certainly answers the question for low and for high frequencies. Now what is left for me is trying to wrap my mind around the intermediate frequencies, say 100-1000Hz.

Comment: jippie, see the transfer function in my post. It gives the answer (when both parts are effectiv).

Comment: @RespawnedFluff jw is inbuilt into Xc i.e. Xc = \$\dfrac{1}{j\omega C}\$

Comment: I realized that, but then you also claim "without using complex numbers"... Your Vout/Vin is a complex number! If you calculate its magnitude... it's exactly 1, of course.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff it was without using complex numbers - at that point Xc could be just regarded as "Z". I don't understand your point.

Comment: Hey why have you deleted your comment? Shall we delete this little conversation or are you going to say something more?

Comment: Actually, I am: while [other] people can't agree on the sign of the capacitive reactance, they seem to always define it as real, so including *j* in it as you did is quite... original.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff where are we going with this?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the LTspice illustration of the equivalent circuit that LvW analyzed (compared to the original transistor circuit):

[image]

Note that in the original circuit Vc and Ve do shift a little bit (in the same direction) at the transition, but this can be ignored as you see.

And if you want "proof by LTspice" of this latter superposition problem, you could do the following by stepping the AC voltage sources:

[image]

In these plots I've selected just the (Vc=1, Ve=0), (Vc=0, Ve=1) and finally (Ve=1, Vc=1) data.

The intuition behind solving this latter equivalent circuit this is simple: whatever magnitude you low-pass from the Vc source you add it to the 180-shifted magnitude that you high-pass from the Ve source. So their sum is constant in general. The formal proof of this is in LvW's answer. If you want to make LTspice "prove" this sum you need to put both partial circuits explicitly on the same schematic as shown below. (I don't know how to make LTspice add parametrized results for different parameter values.)

[image]

To pick a particular abscissa point to verify this numerically, say, corresponding to the -3dB magnitude (\$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$, which is the same for both filters obviously) the phase of the low-pass-ed signal is -45 degrees there, and the phase of the high-passed one is -135 degrees. As expected this gives a magnitude of 1 and -90 degrees phase:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \angle {-45}^{\circ} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \angle {-135}^{\circ} = \Big(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}j \Big) + \Big(-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}j \Big) = -j = 1\angle {-90}^{\circ} $$

---

Finally, here's a re-stated proof that doesn't resort to s-domain (since you don't really need it here), nor use original definitions of reactance. You have two voltage dividers, one for each of those sources

$$ V_{co} = V_{c} \frac {\frac{1}{j\omega C}}{R+\frac{1}{j\omega C}} = V_{c} \frac {1}{1+j\omega RC} $$

$$ V_{eo} = V_{e} \frac {R}{R+\frac{1}{j\omega C}} = V_{e} \frac {j\omega RC}{1+j\omega RC} $$

Since \$V_c=-V_e\$, and by superposition:

$$ V_{sum} = V_{co} + V_{eo} = - V_{e} \frac {1}{1+j\omega RC} + V_{e} \frac {j\omega RC}{1+j\omega RC} = V_{e} \frac{-1+j\omega RC}{1+j\omega RC} $$

It makes more sense to express the transfer function relative to \$V_e\$ than to \$V_c\$ because the former is in-phase with the input signal (transistor's base).

$$ \frac{V_{sum}}{V_{e}} = \frac{-1+j\omega RC}{1+j\omega RC} $$

Now this is a complex number of the form \$ \frac{-z^*}{z}\$ (where * denotes the complex conjugate), so its magnitude is [always 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C%28-z*%2Fz%29%7C); this is a trivial math fact since \$z=a+bi\$ and \$-z^*=-a+bi\$ have the same magnitude, namely \$|z|=a^2+b^2 = (-a)^2+b^2=|-z^*|\$.

The phase is a different matter, and it's not constant since [it is basically the function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+arg%28%28-1%2B+i+x%29+%2F+%281%2B+i+x%29%29+)

$$ f(x) = \arg\Big(\frac{-1+jx}{1+jx}\Big) $$

[image]

Clearly at \$x \to 0\$ it is the phase of \$-1\$ so \$\pm \pi\$, i.e. plus or minus 180 degrees. So it starts [at low frequency] in exact opposite phase of the emitter voltage, i.e. in phase with the collector voltage. As  \$x \to \infty \$ [the limit is zero](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+arg%28%28-1%2B+i+x%29+%2F+%281%2B+i+x%29%29+x+-%3E+infinity), so it becomes in phase with the emitter voltage at high enough frequency.

To do get more insinght by hand, first note that \$\arg(z_1/z_2) = \arg(z_1)-\arg(z_2)\$ (See [eq 10 in this handout and proof idea](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/arg_11.pdf)). So

$$f(x) = \arg(-1+ix) - \arg(1+ix) $$

For \$x>0\$, the right half of this subtraction this is just \$ \arctan x \$, but the left is 
\$ \pi + \arctan (-x) \$. [Since](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=atan%28-x%29) \$\arctan (-x) = -\arctan(x)\$, you finally have

$$ f(x) = \pi - 2 \arctan (x) $$

This is the [same function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cpi+-+2+%5Carctan+%28x%29) but only for \$x>0\$. I guess that's why WA didn't automatically simplify it like this.

[image]

To actually make it look like in the Bode plot, you need to do a semilog plot, which I don't know how to do in WA (I think that requires the paid version), but... gnuplot does this easily:

```
gnuplot> set xrange [1:1E5]       
gnuplot> set logscale x                      
gnuplot> plot (180 / pi) * (pi - 2 * atan(2 * pi * 8E-4 * x))
```

8E-4 is the RC constant in this case.

[image]

I somewhat unwisely set Vc to be 0 phase in the previous LTspice sims/plots when I should have done that with Ve. With that change the theory agrees with the simulation perfectly:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a first-order allpass filter with the following properties:

- Both output voltages (magnitudes) are equal (collector resp. emitter): Therefore, **v,c=-v,e**.
- Using the superposition principle, the output voltage across the common load resistor R6 (sum of a lowpass and a highpass output) is

  **v,out=v,e[sR5C2/(1+sR5C2)]-v,e[1/(1+sR5C2)]**
- Hence: **v,out/v,e=(sR5C2-1)/(sR5C2+1)**.

  This first-order allpass function has a unity magnitude (equal magnitudes for numerator and denominator) for all frequencies - as long as the frequency-dependence of the transitor gain can be neglected.

Note: The influence of the very large load resistor R6 was neglected.

Comment: I haven't used s-domain for over 20 years, so your second bullet is a bit too summarized for me to grasp.

Comment: But it is nothing else than simple math (common denominator for two expressions). And, as the next step, the magnitude is found for s=jw. Thats all.

Comment: @jippie: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C%281+-+i+w+R+C%29%2F%281+%2B+i+w+R+C%29%7C The part assuming R, C, w positive being relevant here. If you're still confused about that, ask M.SE cause it's just a simple complex math problem at this point.

Comment: @LvW I think the formula should be H(s) = \$\dfrac{sCR-1}{sCR+1}\$

Comment: @Andy, thank you - you are right. The magnitude remains the same, but the phase starts at -180 deg. I have corrected the formulas.